# How I can embed word document in metro app (winRT)

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am writing app that need embed word document in itself. since I didn't find any workaround for it in internet and I assume it's impossible so what is the other suggestion. actually the reason that I need to embed is that I want to prevent user from printing it and files are encrypted on device so app should decrypt it before showing it

What is the best suggestion?

p.s: word files could be change to any format eg OpenXML and for next version App also should be able to show Exel, Pdf and PowerPoint files to user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to accomplish this.  It would be very difficult (read impossible) to build your own Word rendering engine into a Store app and there is no out of the box control to do this.  The best way to prevent a user from printing an Office doc is to use [Information Rights Management](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/information-rights-management-in-office-2010-HA010354260.aspx) on the doc itself.  That way, the doc would carry the protection and your Store app would be able to launch Word (or Excel or PowerPoint) to open the doc using the [Launcher class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx).

Per edit:  Yes.  That is assuming that the user will provide (or you already have) a decryption key for the doc.

Comment: thanks @JP Alioto. I think you are right. I also didn't find anything. And it seems your way it pretty works. It means I need decrypt file into memory as IStorageFile and pass it to Launcher class. right?

Answer (score 0):

SyncFusion has some controls for working with Word documents [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt). Maybe these would work.